# Error with durations created from a data.table using lubridate & dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lubridate

I'm trying to aggregate some data stored in a `data.table`, and then create durations (from `lubridate`) from the aggregated data.  When I try that, however, I get an error.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data(lakers)
lakers.dt <- data.table(lakers, key = "player")

durations <- lakers.dt %>%
  mutate(better.date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(player) %>%
  summarize(min.date = min(better.date), max.date = max(better.date)) %>%
  mutate(duration = interval(min.date, max.date))

# Source: local data table [371 x 4]
# 
# player   min.date   max.date
# 1                2008-10-28 2009-04-14
# 2   Aaron Brooks 2008-11-09 2009-04-03
# 3     Aaron Gray 2008-11-18 2008-11-18
# 4       Acie Law 2009-02-17 2009-02-17
# 5  Adam Morrison 2009-02-17 2009-04-12
# 6  Al Harrington 2008-12-16 2009-02-02
# 7     Al Horford 2009-02-17 2009-03-29
# 8   Al Jefferson 2008-12-14 2009-01-30
# 9    Al Thornton 2008-10-29 2009-04-05
# 10 Alando Tucker 2009-02-26 2009-02-26
# ..           ...        ...        ...
# Variables not shown: duration (dbl)
# Warning messages:
#   1: In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# 2: In format.data.frame(df, justify = "left") :
#   corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Any ideas what this error means, or where it's coming from?

## Edit:

This still happens when you leave out `dplyr` and just do everything in `data.table`.  Here's the code I used:

```
lakers.dt[, better.date := ymd(date)]
durations <- lakers.dt[, list(min.date = min(better.date),
                              max.date = max(better.date)), by = player]
(durations[, duration := interval(min.date, max.date)])
# Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(format(rn, right = TRUE),  : 
#   length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# 2: In cbind(player = c("", "Aaron Brooks", "Aaron Gray", "Acie Law",  :
#   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what you mean by `do` after the `summarise`, but it still happens when you do this entirely in `data.table`.  I'll update the post to reflect that.

Comment: I think the output of `interval(` is not a vector. `is.vector(new_interval(ymd(20090101), ymd(20090201)))
#[1] FALSE`  It has 3 slots

Comment: @akrun that may be the problem, thanks.  I guess I can save the number of days apart as a numeric variable or something like that.

Comment: Why are you using `interval` here in the first place? What value it adds? You can just use `paste`, for example `durations[, duration := paste(min.date, max.date)]`. Also, when using `:=` within `data.table`, you are modifying in place, so `durations <- lakers.dt` doesn't have a real meaning because you also updated `lakers.dt`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Whoops!  You're right, `:=` was not doing what I thought it was doing.  I was trying to aggregate by player.  I updated it, and now it should run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by converting the `interval` output to either `character` class (as the `interval` output is not a `vector`) or wrap with `as.duration` (from @Jake Fisher)

```
durations <- lakers.dt %>%
        mutate(better.date = ymd(date)) %>%
        group_by(player) %>%
        summarize(min.date = min(better.date), max.date = max(better.date)) %>%
        mutate(duration= as.duration(interval(min.date, max.date))
     )
```

Or use `as.vector` which will coerce it to `numeric` class.

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem, thanks.  Storing it as a character variable is less useful than storing it as a duration, at least for my purposes.  So I preferred `mutate(duration = as.duration(interval(min.date, max.date)))`.

Comment: @JakeFisher Yes, the `as.vector` also coerce it to the duration